# GridView with images retrieved from bytes

Tags: c#, image, excel, gridview

I want to export one gridview table to excel format.
The most simple and fast forward solution that I found is from Math Berseth
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html

This solution works fine and was accepted by client. But now, after some months, a new feature was requested: "Just put one image logo in excel"

This is freak me out. I can't put the System.Drawing.Image in a System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image cause they are completely different, but I'm not able to just put a Path cause the excel generated will be send in e-mails so Directory structure can't be considered.

So, can I put images retrieved from bytes in Gridview to export in Math model, or exist some other way?

edit..

I walk few more steps but I'm still far away from my goal.
I can embedded images in html files using String Base64

Something like:

```
private string MakeImageSrcData(string filename) {
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
  fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
  return "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
}
```

...

```
string base64 = MakeImageSrcData("D:\\Proj\\top_title.png");
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
Image logoEmpresa = new Image();
logoEmpresa.ImageUrl = base64;
tc.Controls.Add(logoEmpresa);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
table.Rows.Add(tr);
```

This works fine with IE and FF but nothing whit excel :/

I tried spreadsheet xml, but as MSDN describes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_ss%3adata) there are no support to image type.

Some other idea?

Answer (score 1):

This method works by outputting the gridview as text containing an HTML table. I would imagine you could prepend the string with a string containing an `<img>` tag pointing to your logo somewhere on an accessible web site.

Give it a try.

**Comment**

I added the following before line 61 in the GridViewExportUtil.cs file in the referenced demo:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<img src='http://localhost/WebApplication2/wand.gif' />");
```

The image was available at the specified URL, and rendered correctly in Excel.

Comment: Nice, I thought in this. And actually I can do this using System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image and putting a control inside a TableRow. But as I'm working in intranet env I can't count with a accessible web site.

Comment: @Luis: The `Image` control winds up rendering as an HTML `<img>` tag eventually, and will be subject to the same limitations as any image. I'm not certain if there is a way to encode the image in such a way that it is *embedded* with the page. I write apps for an Intranet environment as well, and found that placing the image in the same web application as the page that generated the grid view was usually enough to make my Intranet customers happy. If it isn't, I recommend trying out your company's public website or some offsite hosting.

Comment: I've found a way to embedded the image in html using string base64. And until works fine with Internet Explorer and Firefox but nothing with Excel. I've tried spreadsheet xml but image content is not supported. I keep with no solution with embedded images in excel.